# Spring EntityManager is Closed

Tags: java, spring, dao

I want to search for username which is not unique. I implemented below code in DAO and it gives error `HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed`.

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Client client) {
        entityManager.persist(client);
    }

public Client findByUsername(String username) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Client.CheckUsername");
          query.setParameter("username", username);
    return (Client) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Query: `@NamedQuery(name="Client.CheckUsername", query="SELECT c.username FROM Client c WHERE c.username = :username")`

Service:

```
@Autowired 
    ClientDAO clientDAO;

    public Client findClientByUsername(String username){
        System.out.println("findclientbyusername: " + username);
        return clientDAO.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public boolean isUsernameUnique(String username) {
        Client client = findClientByUsername(username);
        System.out.println("isusernameunique?: " + username);
        System.out.println(client);
        return (client == null || ((username != null) && client.getUsername() == username));
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: My guess it that you have this error in your controller when serializing the object before returning it. Can you enter in debug mode place a breakpoint just after this method execution?

Comment: How and where is your `entityManager` instance created?

Comment: I would like to see the service from which this method is called

Comment: I added service class and entityManager which I call in DAO just for saving

Comment: Are you sure isUsernameUnique is transactional?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski  I made it Transactional and got this new error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.pr.model.Client

Comment: Your request is returning just a string, the username column. Are you using hibernate? Try "SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.username = :username" to return the whole entity. How is your entity manager created?

Comment: @alfcope Should I return object instead of returning a column which is string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to change your query because it is returning a string, not an object. `findByUsername` function returns object.

```
@NamedQuery(name="Client.CheckUsername", query="SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.username = :username")
```

Service:

```
@Autowired 
ClientDAO clientDAO;

public Client findClientByUsername(String username){
      return clientDAO.findByUsername(username);
}

public boolean isUsernameUnique(String username) {
    Client client = findClientByUsername(username);
     return (client == null || ((username != null) && client.getUsername() == username));
```

dao:

```
public Client findByUsername(String username) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Client.CheckUsername");
          query.setParameter("username", username);
    return (Client) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

And I strongly recommend you to use DEBUG feature instead of printing variables out in the functions.